# how to avoid user to click outside popup window javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to avoid user to click outside popup window javascript ?

Comment: Wow. I love the details. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: @goreSplatter: I had to laugh :-D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid clicking of the content you can place a div with a fixed position over all the content. That prevents the user from clicking on everything that is not inside this div. I use this for some error reporting on a site.

Html:

```
<div id="error_wrapper">
    <div id="site_error">
        Error:
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div#error_wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);

}

div#site_error {
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for not going straight to a framework. Simple demo based on your HTML/CSS: http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/2CrX5/

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're asking about a modal dialog box. If so, have a look at the [jQuery UI modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal).

It will open up a dialog box with custom HTML content, and the rest of the page will be grayed-out and un-clickable. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to ask "can you prevent users from clicking outside a popup window", no, you can't. At least not with JavaScript. Just imagine how annoying that would be.

You need "deeper" access to the browser than what a bunch of JavaScript sitting on a webpage has in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a popup div follow the cursor with a mousemoveevent! I can see some flaws with the method, though.